# Compound statements in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I was browsing some sample Objective-C code and found an interesting portion that used syntax I hadn't seen before. The code below isn't from the sample, it's just an example.

```
MyObject *obj = ({
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    [obj performSomeSetup];
    obj.someProperty = someValue;
    obj;
});
```

After doing some digging I've found that this is called a [compound statement](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), and is a feature of C. Using this sort of syntax seems like a clean way of encapsulating object creation inside a method, and I've begun using this sort of syntax for class constructors like below, as well as in object creation like above.

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValue:(id)someValue {
    return ({
        MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
        obj.somePrivateProperty = someValue;
        obj;
    });
}
```

I like this syntax quite a lot, but am unclear if this is abusing a feature that is not meant to be used this way. So I guess I'm asking is there any reason that I shouldn't be using this type of syntax?

Comment: More properly, it's GNU extension to C. It's not part of the C standard. You shouldn't use it in code that you intend to compile under MSVC, because Microsoft's compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most practical use is that creating a block gives you local variables (which will go away automatically after its end).

For the uses you posted it does no harm, and will probably make no effect depending on the optimization. However it tents to make it less maintainable and readable if overused.

This:

```
MyObject *obj = ({
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    [obj performSomeSetup];
    obj.someProperty = someValue;
    obj;
});
```

Can be reduced to the simpler form:

```
MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
[obj performSomeSetup];
obj.someProperty = someValue;
```

And similarly, this:

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValue:(id)someValue {
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.somePrivateProperty = someValue;
    return obj;
}
```

Is much simpler than the unnecessary block:

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValue:(id)someValue {
    return ({
        MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
        obj.somePrivateProperty = someValue;
        obj;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to use. The code does exactly the same. Value is computed and then returned from the method.

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValue:(id)someValue {
    return ({
        MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
        obj.somePrivateProperty = someValue;
        obj;
    });
}
```

Is the same as:

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValue:(id)someValue {
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.somePrivateProperty = someValue;
    return obj;
}
```

The only difference that in first case you have 2 extra lines of code.